# How to get the sum of a column in a listview android?

Tags: java, android, sql

I am trying to get the total of numbers in an sql table,
i first connected between android and sql but i can't
sum the numbers in the table column and show them
in a textview,like i want to get the total
of numbers in a column then
display them in a text view
,can someone help me with this task?

here is the code i used for
the listview

```
public class MyAppAdapter extends BaseAdapter         //has a class viewholder which holds
    {
        public class ViewHolder
        {
            TextView textDate;
            TextView textTotal;
            TextView textLastTotal;
            TextView textCount;
            TextView textTaxs;

        }

        public List<ClassListItems2> parkingList;

        public Context context;
        ArrayList<ClassListItems2> arraylist;

        private MyAppAdapter(List<ClassListItems2> apps, Context context)
        {
            this.parkingList = apps;
            this.context = context;
            arraylist = new ArrayList<ClassListItems2>();
            arraylist.addAll(parkingList);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return parkingList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) // inflating the layout and initializing widgets
        {

            View rowView = convertView;
            ViewHolder viewHolder= null;
            if (rowView == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listcontent2, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.textDate = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.date);
                viewHolder.textLastTotal = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.lasttotal);
                viewHolder.textTaxs = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.date3);
                viewHolder.textCount = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.InvoicescCount);
                viewHolder.textTotal = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.total);
                rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else
            {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            // here setting up names and images
            viewHolder.textDate.setText(parkingList.get(position).getDate()+"");
            viewHolder.textTotal.setText(parkingList.get(position).getTotal());
            viewHolder.textLastTotal.setText(parkingList.get(position).getLasttotal());
            viewHolder.textTaxs.setText(parkingList.get(position).getTaxs());
            viewHolder.textCount.setText(parkingList.get(position).getInvoicecount());





            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //What happens when you click on a place!



                }
            });

            return rowView;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This Adapter is feed with a Collection (List) in his constructor.

To know total numbers, in Activity/Fragment that handle that Collection use:

`parkingList.size()`

To get sum:

```
float total;

for (ClassListItems2 actualItem : parkingList) {
   total += actualItem.getTotal()
}
```

All of this logic must be executed in Activity/Fragment, never in Adapter because the Adapter only got presentation/visual logic.

Comment: i really can't get the idea, can you explain to me more?

Comment: You have an Activity/Fragment that creates the Adapter. This Adapter to show data in screen needs a List, and you pass that List in constructor Adapters.
You should apply this logic in Activity/Fragment, get List, calculate total (list.size()) and iterate the List to know how is the total (for each)